# "pip install jep" got an error "ld: library not found for -lpython2.7"

Tags: python, installation, pip

== Environment

- Mac OSX 10.9.1
- Installed python 2.7.3, python 3.3
- python installed directory: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`

I tried to install jep using `pip install jep`

but I got an error

```
`ld: library not found for -lpython2.7`
```

I tried to add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib`
to $PATH

but it doesn't work.

Is there anyone who can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a quick look at `jep`, it appears that its installation procedure in `setup.py` is making some simplifying and incorrect assumptions about where to find the Python interpreter shared library to link with.  As it stands on OS X, it appears to be allowing the library default search path to default to the standard library paths, including `/usr/lib`.  If you are not using one of the system-supplied Pythons, as in your case, the correct library is not found there.  What `jep` should be doing is using the `python-config` command corresponding to the compiler in use to find the shared library location;  for example, if using a python.org 2.7:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7-config --ldflags
-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config
-ldl -framework CoreFoundation -lpython2.7
```

I'm also guessing that you have not installed the complete Xcode command line tools package for Xcode 5 in OS X 10.9 and so there is no `libpython2.7.dylib` in `/usr/lib`.  If you do so, by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

you will now find a symlink for `libpython2.7.dylib` and if you rerun `pip install jep`, you will no longer get the `library not found` error.  However, the `jep` extension module will now be linked to the system Python 2.7 and not to the newer Python 2.7 you installed.

```
$ otool -L /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jep.so
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jep.so:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.5)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
```

That should be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python`.

I suggest you open an issue on the `jep` project bug tracker to get the problem fixed.